# Laravel 8: Session::forget() not working in blade file

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-blade

I have a blade file **thanks.blade.php** where I put two sessions **grand_total and order_id**. When I refresh the page session still exists.
I want when I refresh the page the session should be destroyed. I have written the session forget code at the end. Is it correct? I think it's not correct then how to write it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Thanks</title>
    <link href="{{ url('css/front_css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('css/front_css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('css/front_css/prettyPhoto.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('css/front_css/price-range.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('css/front_css/animate.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('css/front_css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('css/front_css/responsive.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="{{ url('js/front_js/html5shiv.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/front_js/respond.min.js') }}"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="{{ asset('images/ico/android-icon-192x192.png')}}">

</head>
<!--/head-->

<body>

    <!-- Header Part -->
    @include('layouts.front_layout.front_header')

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1 class="display-3">Thank You!</h1>
        <p class="lead"><strong>Your Order Is Successfully Place</strong></p>
        <p class="lead">Your Order number is {{Session::get('order_id')}} and grand total is PK. {{Session::get('grand_total')}}</p>

        <hr>
        <p>
            <strong>Please check your email</strong> for further instruction. Having trouble? <a href="{{url('contactus')}}">Contact us</a>
        </p>
        <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{url('/')}}" role="button">Continue to homepage</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <!--/Footer-->
    @include('layouts.front_layout.front_footer')

    <script src="{{ url('js/front_js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/front_js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script> 
    <script src="{{ url('js/front_js/main.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
    
    <php Session::forget('grand_total'); Session::forget('order_id'); ?>
```

Comment: You have to better session use in controller

Comment: @A.ANoman I have also try in controller but not work for me.

Comment: The pull method will retrieve and delete an item from the session in a single statement:
`$value = $request->session()->pull('key', 'default');` from laravel doc.
Or use inside your controller it will work you might be missing something.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir thanks. it make sense. but it not fine for want to move the session to next page.

Comment: @MuqadarAli try this and see if it works `{{ Session::forget('grand_total') }}` if it's still not work then write Session with full namespace.

Comment: @MuqadarAli I am grateful of my effort that helps to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use following code below

```
@php 
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::forget('grand_total'); 
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::forget('order_id');  
@endphp
```

It is working fine for me. I have just now used in my project.